# unbind not working

Tags: jquery, hover, unbind

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to get the "hover" not to apply to text3.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

runIt();

});

function runIt(){
$('#myText').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');

})
.click(function(){
    runIt();
})
.html('text 1')
.fadeIn(1000)
.delay(1000)
.fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).html('text 2');
})
.fadeIn(1000)
.delay(1000)
.fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).html('text 3').unbind('hover');
})
.fadeIn(1000);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is actually a shortcut, so to unbind you'll need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event handlers it created, you'll need to specify *those* events, [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), like this:

```
$(this).html('text 3').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

As a side-tip, [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) takes a function, so instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  runIt();
});
```

You can just do:

```
$(document).ready(runIt);
```

Or the shortcut format, passing a handler [directly to the jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3):

```
$(runIt);
```

All of the above will have the same effect here.